# Disable the header click in grouping in Angular 2 MultiSelect Dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, angular, multi-select

I am using angular 2 multiselect, I want to disable the header click in case of group selection. I need grouping just for logical grouping not for selection, so please suggest how can I disable header click, its should not select child items.

This is the plugin I am using https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/groupby

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="otherSkillList" formControlName="otherskills" [(ngModel)]="selectedotherSkill" [settings]="otherSkillSettings" (onSelect)="onOtherSkillSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="onOtherSkillDeSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onotherSkillSelectAll($event)"
                            (onDeSelectAll)="onOtherSkillDeSelectAll($event)">
                        </angular2-multiselect>


this.otherSkillSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  text: 'Select ' + this.adminPage.OtherSkillsOtherServices,
  enableCheckAll: false,
  enableFilterSelectAll: false,
  searchPlaceholderText: 'Search ' + this.adminPage.OtherSkillsOtherServices,
  enableSearchFilter: true,
  badgeShowLimit: 5,
  limitSelection: 8,
  groupBy: "category",
  disabled: false
};
```

Somehow, using CSS, I tried removing the checkbox for all the the headers, but the header itself is still clickable. In below, "Front-End Skills" is still clickable & selects all below items in that group.

[image]

Comment: Have you found a way to achieve this?